# How do I access global joomla configuration values using codes?

Tags: component, global-configuration

I have a custom table in a view which uses JModelLegacy instead of JModelList since the data source isn't a database. But I still want to use the global default-list-limit value for fetching values from the source. How do I access this, or any other global config values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JFactory::getApplication()->get('list_limit');`

I suppose I got a bit confused by the jargon ambiguity and so did my google searches for the same. Feel free to mark this as a duplicate question if it is.